# Redirect user to angular app after login with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I am trying to build an application in nodejs and angular 6, where the login is done with node and after successful authentication the user is redirected to an angular application. I have looked at many resources online but only seem to find examples of either angular apps with login screens (that call nodejs API endpoints to pass user credentials), or with nodejs using express and Passport. If anyone can point me in the right direction for an example of this I would be extremely greatful.

Comment: how user provides credential if it's not browser login screen is it something on terminal or where do user enters credentials ?

Comment: @GaneshP the login screen will be a simple html page with a form containing a username and password field served by NodeJS. After the form is submitted, NodeJS will authenticate the user and redirect to the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a repo similar with what you're looking for.

> Here's the link to the project:  **[ngx-express-passport-setup](https://github.com/KShewengerz/ngx-express-passport-setup)**
>
> You can clone it & try testing it on your environment. Setup instruction is provided.

Provided with all the instructions on ReadMe.Md for someone who wants to use **Passport via local, google+, facebook and twitter** Step by Step.

This project uses Angular5, NodeJS and ExpressJS

Hope this will help/guide you with your problem if ever you'll decide on using PassportJS as your Authentication as it is quite actually a popular tool for NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am quite new to NodeJs and Angular (coming from a Golang/PHP background) and just wanted more insight on how to do server side processing and routing. From your repo I can see how you set up the project structure from the angular app to be in the public folder and that is similar to what I am trying to achieve. Will spend some time going through your code and looking into PassportJS, thanks!

Comment: @RyanDelport mind if you'll upvote it if my answer helps you with your problem ? That would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: sorry about that, I tried to upvote it immediately after replying, but it showed a popup with something along the lines of "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by XXX are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score". As soon as I figure it out I will upvote it. Thanks again